# Custom ConfigurationSection implementation for Service Fabric

Tags: c#, configuration, azure-service-fabric

Is there an equivalent to `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection` in Service Fabric?

I am trying to port existing application to Service Fabric and I cannot find any examples of how to implement configuration sections.

For example if I have in `app.config`:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="MySection" type="Company.Core.MyConfiguration">
        <section name="Watermark" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<MySection>
    <Watermark>
       <add key="FileName" value="some.png" />
    </Watermark>
</MySection>
```

And implementation of `ConfigurationSection`:

```
public class MyConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
{
    private readonly Watermark _watermark = new Watermark();

    public WatermarkConfiguration WatermarkConfiguration
    {
        get
        {
            return new WatermarkConfiguration
                {
                    FileName = _watermark.FileName
                };
        }
    }

    public class Watermark
    {
        private readonly NameValueCollection _watermark = 
            ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MySection/Watermark") as NameValueCollection;

        [ConfigurationProperty("FileName")]
        public string FileName
        {
            get { return _watermark["FileName"]; }
            set { _watermark["FileName"] = value; }
        }
    }
}

public class WatermarkConfiguration
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the code I can reference this configuration like:

```
var myConfiguration = new MyConfiguration();
var watermarkName = myConfiguration.WatermarkConfiguration.FileName;
```

I am hoping someone has come across this before and could share an insight into their implementation changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't have extendable ConfigurationSections. Service config is done through configuration packages in Service Fabric - basically a version-able set of config files which is part of your overall service package that you deploy to a cluster ([see here for more info on this structure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-application-model/#describe-a-service)).

The config package contains whatever config files you want in any format - XML, JSON, YAML, whatever. There is one special config file you can use called Settings.xml. Service Fabric has C# APIs that look a lot like the System.Configuration classes to access settings in that file.

For example, give this config in Settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Settings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric">

  <Section Name="IoTHubConfigInformation">
    <Parameter Name="ConnectionString" Value="blah" />
  </Section>

</Settings>
```

You would do this:

```
string iotHubConnectionString =
            this.Context.CodePackageActivationContext
                .GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config")
                .Settings
                .Sections["IoTHubConfigInformation"]
                .Parameters["ConnectionString"]
                .Value;
```

But you can't define your own sections like you do with System.Configuration. Instead, you'll have to provide some wrapper classes.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Anyway, is this something that will be coming to Service Fabric? It seems like handling configuration should be easier.

Comment: I have it in the backlog, but can't make any guarantees. I do agree it could be simpler though.